# Does VBA have an equivalent of <i> "text" </i>?

Tags: html, vba, excel

Hi I am trying to italicize text using vba. Is there a VBA equivalent to HTMLs *"Text"*?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say "no", they are two different coding languages. VBA you need to write in that you want the range italicized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following sample VBA code snippet (font in *Italic*):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Font.Italic = True
```

or set *Italic*/**Bold** like the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
```

(re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194438.aspx)

In more general case, you can apply this technique to the entire text in Excel `Cell` or just to a part of it as shown below:

```
'demonstrate font Italic/Bold applied to part of Excel cell
Sub DemoFontItalicBold()
    Range("A1").Value = "This is Just a Sample Text"

   'display "A1" 4 initial chars in bold/italic typeface
    Range("A1").Characters(1, 4).Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"

    'set the word "Sample" in Italic typeface
    Range("A1").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find("Sample", Range("A1").Value, 1), Len("Sample")).Font.Italic = True

    'set the word "Text" in bold typeface
    Range("A1").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find("Text", Range("A1").Value, 1), Len("Text")).Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```